# monacaでnend広告を別ウインドウで開く方法

Tags: monaca

monacaのサイトのドキュメントにある以下の方法で
nend広告を実装するとデバッカーでは別のブラウザーが起動しますが
iOSでビルドするとアプリ内で開いてしまいます。
コルドバ2.9のころにはできていました
3.5になりコードをドキュメントのとおりに変更したのですが機能しません、、

http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/sampleapp/tips/external_services/nend_ad/

何かプラグインの設定が抜けているのかと思いましたが
inappbrowserは有効にしています

このコードで正常に機能して方はいらっしゃるのでしょうか？

サポートに連絡しても有料の見積もりのテンプレしか返って来なくて困っています
ご教示頂けると幸いです

Answer (score 4, accepted):

user7987さん。

以下のコードを書いてみました。これをuser7989さんのiOS環境で動かしてみてください。

- バナー型広告で試しています。アイコン型広告だと、やり方がちょっと異なるかもしれません

詳しくはちょっと調べてみないと解りませんが、もしかして、nendの仕様が変更になったのかもしれません。自分の記憶が正しければ、以前はdivタグのnend_adspace_xxxxの中に直接広告タグは生成されなかったと思うのですが....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script>

      addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);

        function onLoad() {
            //nendの広告タグのロードにラグがあるので、決め打ちで処理を遅延させています。
            var TIME_FOR_WAITING_NEND_AD = 500;

            setTimeout(function () {

                var nendAdSpace = document.querySelector('div[id^=nend_adspace]');
                var nendAdAnchors = nendAdSpace.querySelectorAll('a');

                for (var i = 0; i < nendAdAnchors.length; i++) {
                    var hrefShelter = nendAdAnchors[i].href;
                    nendAdAnchors[i].removeAttribute('href');
                    nendAdAnchors[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                        window.open(hrefShelter, '_system', 'location=no');
                    }, false);
                }                

            }, TIME_FOR_WAITING_NEND_AD);
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
    var nend_params = {"media":xxxxxxx, "site":xxxxxxx, "spot":xxxxxxx, "type":1, "oriented":2};
  </script>
    <div id="nend_wrapper"><script src="http://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script></div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

同様の症状でしたが、サンプルを以下のように修正することで改善しました。

nend_links[i].onclick = function(){window.open(href); return false;}
↓
nend_links[i].onclick = function(){window.open(href, '_system'); return false;}