# monacaでnend広告を開くとアプリに戻れなくなる

Tags: javascript, monaca, html, nend

monacaでnend広告を開くとアプリに戻れなくなりまして、過去のスタックオーバーフローの質問を見たりネットの情報を見たりして試行錯誤しているのですがうまくいきません。
以下の二つのサイトを見て作成しております。

[monacaでnend広告を別ウインドウで開く方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5969/monaca%E3%81%A7nend%E5%BA%83%E5%91%8A%E3%82%92%E5%88%A5%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%81%A7%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

http://hatopp.wpblog.jp/archives/102

このサイトの通り作成したのですが、広告をクリックしても起動したアプリに戻れないため、window.openのプログラムが走ってないのかなと思いました。それともこのプログラムでは実装できないのでしょうか？

また、私のアプリは広告をクリックしても反応が悪くて数秒後にサイトが開くという形となっています。
上記のプログラムでクリック後に早くサイトを開かすためにはどのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか？

以上の２点をご教授頂けたら幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく`setTimeout()`で指定した時間内に広告が表示されないために`a`タグが取得できず、既存ブラウザではなく`Cordova WebView`を開いて表示している可能性があります。
実際にMonacaデバッガーなどで`a`タグを取得しているか検証した方がよろしいかと思います。

反応が悪い原因は、
1.`Cordova WebView`を開く場合に多少時間を要する。
2.通信速度が遅い。
のいずれかが考えられます。

`a`タグを取得できるまで何回か繰り返すことで回避できるかと思います。

```
addEventListener("load", function() {
    var count = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        var nendAdAnchors = [];
        var nendAdSpace = document.querySelector("div[id^=nend_adspace]");
        if (nendAdSpace != null) {
            nendAdAnchors = nendAdSpace.querySelectorAll("a");
        }
        if (nendAdAnchors.length > 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            for (var i = 0; i < nendAdAnchors.length; i++) {
                (function() {
                    var hrefShelter = nendAdAnchors[i].href;
                    nendAdAnchors[i].removeAttribute("href");
                    nendAdAnchors[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                        var w = window.open(hrefShelter, "_system", "location=no");
                    }, false);
                })();
            }
        } else {
            count++;
console.log(count);
            if (count > 4) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
}, false);
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございました。
上記のプログラムを使用してバナーの広告を開いたのですが、広告サイトに飛ぶ時と飛ばない時がありました。これは、何が問題でこのような現象になるのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ただ実行するだけでなく、[GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/)や`console.log`などで`a`タグを取得しているか、`window.open`が呼び出されているか検証してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
console.logを使用して、aタグを取得して、window.openも呼び出されていることが確認できました。たまにサイトに飛ばなかった理由はこちらの仕様上、window.openの_systemを_blankにしていたためかと思います。
バナーに関してはoTakさんのプログラムを使用することで問題なくできたのですが、ネイティブアドの場合ですと、うまく起動せずwindow.openが呼び出されませんでした。console.logで確認するとvar nendAdSpace = document.querySelector("div[id^=nend_adspace]");がnullとなっていたためにwindow.openが発動しなかったのかと思われます。
なぜnendAdSpaceがnullになってしまうのでしょうか？
もしわかるのであればご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `nend_adspace`が存在しないからです。実際にバナーとネイティブアドのJavaScriptが生成するタグを確認すれば答えが出ます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。申し訳ありません、私の知識不足ですみませんが、バナーとネイティブアドのJavaScriptが生成するタグの確認方法がわからないのです。どのようにして確認をすればよろしいのですか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: GapDebugを使って確認してください。またはブログなどに広告コードを貼り付けて、ブラウザでソースを表示すれば確認できます。

Comment: 上記のことについては解決しました。ありがとうございました。すみませんがこれに関してもう１点質問があります。このプログラムを<iframe>で使用するとwindow.openが起動しなくなってしまったのですが、<iframe>では使えないのでしょうか？